# Как конвертировать один часовой пояс в другой?

Tags: python, datetime

У меня есть строка с временем, допустим, `13:47`, и допустим это время в `'America/New_York'` часовом поясе.

Как мне это время сконвертировать в Московский часовой пояс?

Пробовал вот так:

```
import datetime
import pytz

time = "13:47"
#
tz = 'America/New_York'
tz1 = 'Europe/Moscow'
#
time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%H:%M")
#
time1 = time.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone(tz))
print("In America/New_York " + datetime.datetime.strftime(time1, "%H:%M"))

time2 = time1.astimezone(tz=pytz.timezone(tz1))
print("In Europe/Moscow " + datetime.datetime.strftime(time2, "%H:%M"))
```

Но результат неверный:

> In America/New_York 13:47
> In Europe/Moscow 21:13

Comment: Неплохо бы ещё дату знать. А то в январе и в июле в Москве будет разное время

Comment: Добавил в строку дату, всё равно неверно переводит

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я не уверен, но возможно это связано с тем, что в 1900 году в москве жили еще по юлианскому календарю. А если не указывать дату, то Python автоматически создаст объект `datetime` с датой `1900-01-01`. Попробуйте указать более актуальный год и используйте следующий подход:

```
from datetime import datetime as DT
import pytz

tz1 = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
tz2 = pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow')

dt_tz2 = tz1.localize(DT.strptime("2021-01-01 13:47", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")).astimezone(tz2).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

Судя по примерам Python начинает правильно переводить время для москвы начиная с 1919-07-01:

```
In [248]: tz1.localize(DT.strptime("1900-01-01 13:47", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")).astimezone(tz2).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
Out[248]: '1900-01-01 21:13'

In [249]: tz1.localize(DT.strptime("1919-01-01 13:47", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")).astimezone(tz2).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
Out[249]: '1919-01-01 22:18'

In [250]: tz1.localize(DT.strptime("1920-01-01 13:47", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")).astimezone(tz2).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
Out[250]: '1920-01-01 21:47'

In [251]: tz1.localize(DT.strptime("2000-01-01 13:47", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")).astimezone(tz2).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
Out[251]: '2000-01-01 21:47'

In [252]: tz1.localize(DT.strptime("2021-01-01 13:47", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")).astimezone(tz2).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
Out[252]: '2021-01-01 21:47'

In [253]: tz1.localize(DT.strptime("1919-07-01 13:47", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")).astimezone(tz2).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
Out[253]: '1919-07-01 21:47'

In [254]: tz1.localize(DT.strptime("1919-06-30 13:47", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")).astimezone(tz2).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
Out[254]: '1919-06-30 22:18'
```